# aws-cdk - ApiGateway with Cognito authorizer for a Lambda proxy endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I'm having issues setting up a, API Gateway with a lambda proxy secured by a Cognito userpool.
I am using aws-cdk 0.34.0 in typescript.

The setup I am after is an API Gateway with a single resource that is a proxy for a lambda function. This single endpoint needs to be secured by a Cognito user pool.

The code I am trying is below.

However when I run it I get the following error...

```
apiDeployment (Deployment2E842E9E) No integration defined for method (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: 64f4e3bb-9107-11e9-84f1-999724493159)
    new Deployment (/home/circleci/aws/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway/lib/deployment.ts:69:21)
```

My Typescript code is below

```js
    const backendLambda = new lambda.Function(
      this,
      "CampManager-backendLambda",
      {
        code: new lambda.AssetCode("../server/", AssetPackaging.ZipDirectory),
        handler: "src/index.js",
        timeout: 1000,
        runtime: lambda.Runtime.NodeJS10x
      }
    );

    const backendApi = new api.RestApi(this, "CampManager-backendApi");

    const userPool = new cognito.UserPool(this, "CampManager-userPool", {
      autoVerifiedAttributes: [],
      poolName: "CampManager-userPool",
      signInType: cognito.SignInType.Username,
      usernameAliasAttributes: [
        cognito.UserPoolAttribute.Email,
        cognito.UserPoolAttribute.PhoneNumber
      ]
    });

    const cognitoAuthorizer = new api.CfnAuthorizerV2(
      this,
      "CampManager-authorizer",
      {
        apiId: backendApi.restApiId,
        authorizerType: api.AuthorizationType.Cognito,
        identitySource: ["Authorisation"],
        authorizerUri: userPool.userPoolProviderUrl,
        name: "Cognito"
      }
    );

    backendApi.root.addProxy({
      defaultIntegration: new api.LambdaIntegration(backendLambda),
      defaultMethodOptions: {
        authorizationType: api.AuthorizationType.Cognito,
        authorizerId: cognitoAuthorizer.authorizerId,
        operationName: "Proxy"
      }
    });

    const apiDeployment = new api.Deployment(
      this,
      "CampManager-apiDeployment",
      {
        api: backendApi,
        description: "Camp Manager Deployment"
      }
    );

    const apiStage = new api.Stage(this, "CampManager-apiStage", {
      deployment: apiDeployment
    });
```

Comment: have you found a solution to this by any chance?

Comment: same question here

Comment: I think this is exactly what you are looking for.
http://docs.awssolutionsbuilder.com/aws-solutions-konstruk/latest/api/aws-cognito-apigateway-lambda/